# Google cloud endpoints authorization with retrofit

Tags: android, google-cloud-endpoints, retrofit

Is there a way to set googleaccountcredential in the retrofit restadapter for authorization of google cloud endpoints api.

Answer (score -1):

Try to use the "Google Cloud API URL" as the base URL and proceed with the normal configuration of the retrofit. It should be easy to handle.

Here is a link to a tutorial that will help you to get started with the retrofit. 
[Tutorial](http://blog.robinchutaux.com/blog/a-smart-way-to-use-retrofit/) Link.